# When c macros are expanded why does the code get so big?

Tags: c, gcc, macros, line-numbers

I've been experimenting with C's macros, and decided to expand them to see the replacement. When I supply gcc with `-E`, I get 800 lines of code just for this simple code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define TEN 10

int main(void) {
    printf("hello world %d", TEN);
    return 0;
}
```

My questions:

- Why do I get so many lines!?
- How can C run so fast with that many lines?
- Is that many lines a problem?

Comment: How many lines are there in `stdio.h`?

Comment: You understand that gcc is a compiler and so the number of source lines is not closely related to the performance of the exectable file?

Comment: do not be afraid of that, they will not be part of the generated code, that increase the compile time/memory, but nothing about your executable

Comment: Oh, Ok. Just freaked me out how big it suddenly got.

Comment: @Xilpex these 800 lines are nothing, is much more in c++ when you include 'classical' files as *vector,string,iostream ...*, the equivalent of *stdio* in c++ is *iostream*, and `g++ -E` on a file just containing `#include <iostream>` produces more than 28000 lines ;-)

Comment: C's way of compiling programs made a lot of sense when the language was invented.  After about 40 years, it's a little unwieldy. All but 1 or 2 lines of the big header will be ignored by the compiler: the ones declaring `printf`. It's also declaring macros, types, and external references that your code never uses.  A more interesting thing to look at is what goes into the compiler's output. Your program produces only 8 machine instructions when compiled with gcc - a tiny number. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Ao2daw That's what counts when the program runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The -E option asks gcc to stop after the pre-processor stage without compiling, so what you end up with is (essentially) your system's entire `stdio.h` file copied and pasted in the header of your program. That's definitely where the 800 lines are coming from.

This is not a problem, though, because when you compile your ~800 line program the prototypes of the functions in `stdio.h` that you don't use in your code will not take up space in your executable.

As for 'how does C run so fast with that many lines' it's important to remember that the source code we write is not what the machine executes, the machine executes the compiled binaries that the compilers produce from the source code.

If you remove `#define TEN 10` and change the printf line to `printf("hello world %d",10);` and run `gcc` with `-E` again, you'll find almost exactly the same ~800 line source file as before. This is not a sympom of `#define` this is simply how the C pre-processor works, and it's nothing to worry about :)